# add to favorites button help

Tags: iphone

how would an add to favorites button work in order to take the controller selected and add it to a tab bar item, 
i tried using an ibaction to add an entry to an array however i wasnt sure on how to handle this problem.

i would like to add a uibutton that adds an entry to this kind of array format

```
rootArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"entry1", @"entry2",  nil];
```

the tab bar would have two views on the favorite table view and one with all the rest of the cells. i would like to click on the "normal" table view which would take me to the detailview controller already implemented. Afterwards i would like to have a button on the detailviewcontroller that would say something like add to favorites and add this detailview and its cell to the favorites tab controller. i would like to add the uibutton to add the detailview controller in the mentioned format above however im not sure how to do this.

i would appreciate some help in pointing me in the right direction thanks

Comment: What exactly is this array supposed to be doing? 
Also are you trying to add a controller to tab bar on-the-fly?
What is being added to favorites the controller or the data in the controller?

Comment: i updated my post to reflect some changes thanks

Comment: Are you saving your data to some database or is everything saved in an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am assuming u have a database somewhere from where you are getting data for your "normal" tableview. What you need to do is you could add a favorites table or just add a "is_favorite" field to your table.I'd go with the latter option.

With this in place you just have to filter your results. Records with "is_favorite" as true added to the favorites table view while everything (both favorite and non-favorite) appear in the other table view.

For the details view, you could have a `UIBarButton` for adding to favorites. The iphone sdk already has a system button for that. Add the following to you `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks target:self action:@selector(addToFavorites:)];
```

then add a method called `addToFavorites` to your detailviewcontroller class. This will respond to the `IBAction`. Inside `addToFavorites` add some code that will set the `is_favorite` field to true.

I believe all this covers how you could accomplish your task.

**Edit:** The explanation above was based on the assumption you were using a database.

**Update**
Since you are storing everything in an array here's what you could do.
Define the favorites (mutable)array in you YourAppDelegate.h file as you would any normal property.

```
NSMutableArray *favorites;
```

Then inside the `addToFavorites` do something like:

```
YourAppDelegate *app = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[app.favorites addObject:current_detail]; //add whatever detail you selected
```

`favorites` is the array you will be using as the source of data for your favorites table view.

Hope all this makes sense now.

Comment: thanks this has shed some light on how this can be achieved however furthermore i have a few more questions.all my data is stored in an array btw.

what is the is_favorite field? 
i have no idea how to implement this tag? im guessing.

could you please give me a bit of code for this part to get me started thanks.

and for the addToFavorites
i dont know what to use to set the is_Favorite field to true partly because i dont know what is_favorite is. 
thank you for your patience :)

Comment: thanks that does it however one small question left unanswered
what is the current+detail supposed to be??

Comment: Current detail is meant to be the object holding the details of the currently displayed view